# How to find positive indices of columns in a one-hot encoded pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a one-hot encoded pandas dataframe of the form:

**df**

```
      A      B      C      D
ID
#1    2      1      0      1
#2    1      0      0      1
#3    1      1      1      0

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID_1':['#1','#1','#3','#1'], 'ID_2':['#2','#3',np.NaN,'#2'], \
          'ID_3':['#3', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN] }, index=['A','B','C','D'])
```

I would like to transform it to a new dataframe where the indices are the columns and the values correspond to the old indices (a way of pivoting the dataframe). I am only looking for those old indices which had a positive value (corresponding to count) in the original dataframe. Effectively, **df** should look like:

**new_df**

```
      ID_1  ID_2   ID_3
c_id
A     #1     #2     #3      
B     #1     #3            
C     #3      
D     #1     #2
```

I understand I need to pivot the dataframe somehow, but I'm not able to find an effective way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First using `gt` make the df become Boolean then using `mul` , then we sort your column by `isnull` or not .

```
df.gt(0).mul(df.index.values,0).T.replace('',np.nan).apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull),1)
ID  #1   #2   #3
A   #1   #2   #3
B   #1   #3  NaN
C   #3  NaN  NaN
D   #1   #2  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @W-B, but this does not return the IDs as separate columns. It returns a list per row instead.

Comment: @Melsauce it return the df in my end , but simple fixed adding `.apply(pd.Series)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) from numpy to get the position of the values in the order you want and then [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to replace where the value is 0 in the sorted array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = df.values.T
new_df = (pd.DataFrame( data = df.index[np.argsort( -arr, axis=1)].values,
                        index = pd.Index(df.columns,name='c_id'),
                        columns='ID_' + df.index.str[1:])
            .mask(np.sort( -arr, axis=1) == 0,''))
```

then you get

```
print(new_df)
     ID_1 ID_2 ID_3
c_id               
A      #1   #2   #3
B      #1   #3     
C      #3          
D      #1   #2
```